# Angular 4: Get all properties that are decorated with @Input

Tags: angular

I have an input component that has a variety of properties, and some of them are decorated using the `@Input` decorator.

How can I see at runtime which of these properties have the `@Input` decorator?

So for example with the following class:

```
export class MyInputComponent {
    @Input() min: number;
    @Input() max: number;
    ignoreMe: number;
}
```

I want the following result:

`> [ 'min', 'max' ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no official solution for this issue , but if your inputs are used , you can watch their changes and get their names by imlementing `OnChanges` like this :

```
export class MyInputComponent implements OnChanges{
    @Input() min: number;
    @Input() max: number;
    ignoreMe: number;
    list = [];

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {   
      for (let propName in changes) {
         this.list.push(propName); 
    }
    console.log("list :",Array.from(new Set(this.list)));
  }


}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This would mean that these properties need to be changed first, right? I want to get all the properties from the start, not after changing them.

Comment: yes the properties need to be changed , if u are using them they will be changed from the start but if u r just declaring the properties this will not work for u

Comment: This works indeed. Meanwhile I fixed it using a different approach that doesn't use the @Input decorators.